# Querying from xml to excel. Similar to importxml on Google Spreadsheet

Tags: xml, vba, excel

I am trying to use an excel function similar to Google Spreadsheet's importxml.

Here is the code:

```
Function GetData(sURL As String, sItem As String) As Variant
Dim oHttp As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim xmlResp As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim result As Variant
On Error GoTo EH



'open the request and send it
oHttp.Open "GET", sURL, False
oHttp.Send

'get the response as xml
Set xmlResp = oHttp.responseXML
' get Item
GetData = xmlResp.SelectNodes(sItem).Item(0).Text

' Examine output of these in the Immediate window
Debug.Print sName
Debug.Print xmlResp.XML

CleanUp:
On Error Resume Next
Set xmlResp = Nothing
Set oHttp = Nothing
Exit Function
EH:
GetData = CVErr(xlErrValue)
GoTo CleanUp
End Function
```

The following formula will return 192799976.00

```
=GetData("http://api.eve-central.com/api/marketstat?typeid=24692&usesystem=30000142","//sell/min")
```

This formula will return 34

```
=GetData("http://util.eveuniversity.org/xml/itemLookup.php?name=Tritanium","//itemLookup/typeID")
```

I am getting #VALUE! when trying to pull data from this website, but it should be $179.

```
    =GetData("http://www.hotels.com/hotel/details.html?current-location=Chicago%2C+Illinois%2C+United+States+of+America&arrivalDate=10%2F30%2F14&departureDate=10%2F31%2F14&searchParams.rooms.compact_occupancy_dropdown=compact_occupancy_1_2&rooms_=1&rooms%5B0%5D.numberOfAdults=2&children%5B0%5D=0&searchParams.landmark=&hotelId=113158&roomno=1&srsReport=HomePage%7CAutoR%7CHOTEL%7Cthe++drake+Chicago%2C+Illinois%2C+United+States+of+America%7C0%7C0%7C0%7C1%7C1%7C1%7C113158&resolvedLocation=HOTEL%3A113158%3ASRS%3AUNKNOWN&pageName=HomePage&destinationId=&rooms.compact_occupancy_dropdown=compact_occupancy_1_2&landmark=
","//span/strong")
```

Edit 1: Tried to turn @portlandrunner 's sub into a function, but excel says the function is not valid.

```
 Function extract(URL As String) As Variant
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.Navigate2 URL

    ' Wait while IE loading
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set html = IE.Document
    Set spanElement = html.getElementsByTagName("span")

    For Each spn In spanElement
        If Left(spn.innertext, 1) = "$" Then
            extract = spn.innertext
            Exit For
        End If
    Next spn

    'Cleanup
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL in the last example only returns `HTML` not `XML`.

You can get HTML elements by tag or class name using an IE document.  The following code will display the first `<span>` tag with a $ which is $179.

Make sure you:

1. Have a reference to "Microsoft Internet Controls" added
2. Have a reference to "Microsoft HTML Object Library" added
3. Depending on your version of IE you might need to disable protected mode under security settings in the IE internet options menu.

---

```
Sub extract()
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.Navigate2 "http://www.hotels.com/hotel/details.html?current-location=Chicago%2C+Illinois%2C+United+States+of+America&arrivalDate=10%2F30%2F14&departureDate=10%2F31%2F14&searchParams.rooms.compact_occupancy_dropdown=compact_occupancy_1_2&rooms_=1&rooms%5B0%5D.numberOfAdults=2&children%5B0%5D=0&searchParams.landmark=&hotelId=113158&roomno=1&srsReport=HomePage%7CAutoR%7CHOTEL%7Cthe++drake+Chicago%2C+Illinois%2C+United+States+of+America%7C0%7C0%7C0%7C1%7C1%7C1%7C113158&resolvedLocation=HOTEL%3A113158%3ASRS%3AUNKNOWN&pageName=HomePage&destinationId=&rooms.compact_occupancy_dropdown=compact_occupancy_1_2&landmark="

    ' Wait while IE loading
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set html = IE.Document
    Set spanElement = html.getElementsByTagName("span")

    For Each spn In spanElement
        If Left(spn.innertext, 1) = "$" Then
            MsgBox spn.innertext
            Exit For
        End If
    Next spn

    'Cleanup
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

Tested

[image]

---

**Update 2**

Here is how I set this up as a function:

```
Public Function extractURL(url As String, tag As String) As String
    extractURL = ""

    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
    IE.Visible = False
    IE.Navigate2 url

    ' Wait while IE loading
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set html = IE.Document
    Set spanElement = html.getElementsByTagName(tag)

    For Each spn In spanElement
        If Left(spn.innertext, 1) = "$" Then
            extractURL = spn.innertext
            Exit For
        End If
    Next spn

    'Cleanup
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
End Function
```

Sheet Looks like this:

[image]

Formula in Cell `A2` looks like this: `=extractURL(C2,B2)`

*Note:* This page took a while to load (on my slow connection) and sometimes returned nothing from the script.  If I step through the code and force it to wait for the page to finish loading then I always got the right result.  There might be some page scripts still loading data after IE signals that it's done loading.  The only way to get around this is by increasing the wait time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how to implement your code. What are the inputs supposed to be?

Comment: Since I have a lot of URLs I will be scraping this data from, I tried to turn your sub into a function. You can find my code in the original post.

Comment: I've updated the post with a function example.  Not sure functions are the right way to go since your page may have a long lag times as your cells recalculate all the HTML request.

Comment: How would you suggest I go about it if I plan on extracting the same data from thousands of urls?

For now I've found a program that can do it, but it'd definitely if I could just do all the work in excel.

Comment: Personally, I'd run this on a button click event, loop through your cells with URL's and call the function from the loop.  This way you can be sure when the data was last updated and not have to wait minutes every time you make a sheet change for it to recalculate every function.  Just a thought, you can certainly do it the other way too.  Hope this helps.